# How to increase session timeout in .net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session

I have tried to extend the session timeout in my .net core 5.0 application but it seems the application has a default or an overriding method that enables session timeout to less than 30 minutes.

The below are where I have tried configuring the session timeout.

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(48);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Administration/AccessDenied");
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

 services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(48);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

        });
```

What is it am I doing wrong.
Kindly assist.

Comment: Please edit your title so it's not in all-caps - that's widely regarded as the equivalent of shouting.

Comment: Smile... Literarily, am shouting. Cos this issue is already affecting my application.

Comment: What Jon was too polite to go on to: It's considered _really_ rude.

Comment: So you're happy to shout at people who are trying to help you in their own free time? It's inappropriate to take out your frustration on Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 1):

I test your showing codes which should be working, here is the test result:[image] You can see from the picture, the expire time of session is working

So maybe you can try these steps to check what cause your issue:

1. Make sure you are adding the ***app.UseSession();*** in the Startup.cs
2. Check that there are no other places in your code where the session timeout is being set as a shorter time. For example, if you have a middleware that sets the lower session timeout, it could be overriding your configuration.
3. Check that the session middleware is being added after the authentication middleware. The authentication middleware sets its own timeout, and if the session middleware is added before it, it will use that value instead.

Or maybe you can share more information of your project and we can check what may cause your issue.